# Добавить контакт в CSV файл

Tags: java, csv

Подскажите как реализовать. На данный момент имеется метод добавления новой записи в CSV:

```
private static void addContact() {
    String outputFile = "myPhoneBook.csv";
    boolean alreadyExists = new File(outputFile).exists();
    try {
        CsvWriter csvOutput = new CsvWriter(new FileWriter(outputFile, true), ',');

        if (!alreadyExists) {
            csvOutput.write("ID");
            csvOutput.write("Name");
            csvOutput.write("Phone");
            csvOutput.write("City");
            csvOutput.endRecord();
        }

        csvOutput.write(new String(String.valueOf(getLastColumnValue())));
        csvOutput.write("Bruce");
        csvOutput.write("12345");
        csvOutput.write("Plovdiv");
        csvOutput.endRecord();

        csvOutput.close();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

}
```

По заданию нет возможности вставлять дублирующиеся значение для имени и номера телефона. Подскажите как можно реализовать.

Comment: Возьмите любую in-memory базу данных, a в CSV просто сливайте данные оттуда как в persistent storage.

Answer (score 2):

У вас какое-то учебное задание? Проверка уникальности записи хорошо работает в базах данных или хотя бы в коллекциях. Проверять уникальность непосредственно в CSV файле каждый раз перед вставкой новой записи весьма неэффективно с точки зрения производительности, скорости работы программы. Вам надо каждый раз перед добавлением новой записи читать содержимое файла с начала до конца, сравнивая каждую считанную строку с вашей новой записью и, убедившись что в файле нет аналогичной записи, добавить новую запись в конец CSV файла или не добавлять если такая уже есть.